# Rendering to and sampling same texture in one draw call

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl

Is it possible in OpenGL to sample from, and then write to the same texture in one draw call using GLSL?

Answer (score 0):

I think it actually IS possible. I did it like this for GLSL alpha blending:

```
vec4 prevColor = texture(dfFrameTexture, pointCoord);
vec4 result = vec4(color.a) *   color + vec4(1.0 - color.a) * prevColor;
gl_FragColor = result;
```

`dfFrameTexture` is the texture that is being written to with gl_FragColor.

I tested this and it worked. Drawing a white quad onto dfFrameTexture after it's been cleared to black results in a grey quad when I set the color to (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)

Comment: It is possible of course, but it is not advised. It creates a feedback loop, which leads to undefined behavior. Beginning with GL4, it is possible to do this sort of thing if you use image load/store and memory barriers to influence the scheduling of shaders so that data hazards do not produce undefined behavior at runtime. But since you are writing to `gl_FragColor` in this shader I have a feeling GL4 is out of the question...